# Is it necessary to add the mass of the dissolved solute to the mass of the solvent when finding the specific heat capacity of a solution?

Tags: thermodynamics, water

For example lets say I have dissolved 5g of salt in 100g of water. I do an experiment for finding the specific heat capacity of the solution in which I measure the energy transferred and the temperature change caused by the energy transfer. Now I want to calculate specific heat capacity from the equation. Do I add the mass of the salt to that of the water before using it in the equation?

Comment: Use the mass of the solution possibly having measured it before and after taking data.

Comment: So I should take the whole mass of the solution which has a mass of 105g?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you would. Specific heat is [defined](https://www.britannica.com/science/specific-heat) as the energy required to increase the temperature of unit mass of a substance by one unit. If you want to calculate the specific heat of a salt solution, you'd want to consider one unit mass of the solution, which includes the solute. 
So assuming no evaporation, the mass of your system would be 105 grams.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).